# FindFirstFile type problems

Tags: string, winapi, c++-cli

I'm writing a function that will check if there's a jpg file in the given folder. My try at this is as follows:

```
    int containsJpgs(String ^path)
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
        HANDLE hFind;
        hFind = FindFirstFile(path + "*.jpg", &data); // Type error.
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

How do I append a `System::String ^` to a `LPCTSTR`to get `LPCTSTR`? And will the above code work when I do that, or are there other problems?

Comment: Since you are using .NET, why not use `System::IO::Directory::EnumerateFiles()`?

Comment: @James: A link to a tutorial/example would be nice, MSDN doesn't have examples.

Comment: @Igor:  [The MSDN page for `EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx) has examples in C# and VB.NET, but it should be straightforward to convert those to C++/CLI.  Are you looking for an introductory C++/CLI book?

Comment: @James: I don't exactly have time for a book, but a rundown of differences clarifying things would be nice.

Comment: Directory::GetFiles(String^, String^) is supported on any .NET version, EnumerateFiles() is .NET 4.0 only.  And it has a C++/CLI example.

Comment: @Hans: Make this an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

what about [lstrcat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

**EDIT:**
to convert system::string^ to lpctstr I found [this](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/615998-conversion-system-string-lpctstr)

Comment: Now I have to change System::String to LPCTSTR.